# Spinner com SQLite

Tags: android

Olá, boa noite. No meu projeto tenho um `spinner`

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnCategorie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/categories_array"
    android:prompt="@string/categories_prompt" />
```

Esse `spinner` é responsável por adicionar o valor na coluna `CATEGORIE` no meu banco de dados através da classe **InsertProduct.class**.
As categorias que populam esse `spinner` é a seguinte:

```
<string-array name="categories_array">
    <item>Mantimentos</item>
    <item>Açougue</item>
    <item>Peixaria</item>
    <item>Frios</item>
    <item>Hortifruti</item>
    <item>Café da Manhã</item>
    <item>Higiene</item>
    <item>Limpeza</item>
</string-array>
```

Estou convertendo o valor do `spinner` para `String` para inserir no `banco de dados` da seguinte maneira. (**Não sei se é a maneira correta.**)

```
Spinner CATEGORIE = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategorie);
String stringCATEGORIE = CATEGORIE.getSelectedItem().toString();
...
```

Tenho outra classe (**AlterProduct.class**) responsável por alterar os valores dos produtos, gostaria que o `spinner` da classe **AlterProduct.class** retornasse a categoria salva no banco de dados.

Ex: Meu produto foi inserido no banco de dados com a categoria `Frios`, quando o usuário clicasse para alterar o produto, ele retornasse o valor `Frios` no `spinner` da classe **AlterProduct.class**

**Att.**
Giovani Rodrigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que você precisa fazer é consultar o valor no banco de dados e setar o item selecionado no spinner, isso pode ser feito usando o método `setSelection(int position)`

Caso você queira setar o valor pelo texto e não pela posição dele nas opções do spinner esse link pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position

Comment: Qual a diferença em setar pela posição ou pelo valor?

Comment: O método recebe apenas a posição que deve ser setada, caso você não saiba essa posição exatamente você percorre a lista e compara os valores procurando a posição.
No fim você sempre estará passando uma posição que é o que o método pede como parâmetro.

Comment: Por position, ao invés de eu salvar o valor do imte selecionado como string, eu devo salvar como valor int da posição do item?

Comment: Melhor não, pois se você precisar alterar a lista futuramente você pode ter complicações.